# Error al tratar de instalar Angular ( npm i -g @angular/cli )

Tags: angular, cmd

Al tratar de instalar angular globalmente con "npm i -g @angular/cli" me sale ésto:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/cli@13.3.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '8.5.5' }
```

Y luego repite eso varias veces, sólo cambiando el valor asignado a "package:"
Entiendo que lo que me esta queriendo decir es que tengo que tenerversiones mayores a esas? pero segun puedo ver tengo versiones mayores a todas esas! De node me pide la 16.10.0 y segun entiendo tengo esa misma. Y de npm me pide una version mayor o igual a 8.0.0 y tengo la 8.5.5.
Será que no tengo instalada yarn y por eso no me figura y es eso lo que esta causando el error?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que pude darme cuenta... cuando me dice `npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0'` no me está diciendo "mayor igual a la version 8.0.0" sino "menor igual". Eso si que no lo entiendo, porque ">" significa "mayor qué", es "<" el que es "menor que". Pero segun la respuesta a una pregunta similar que encontre por ahí significa eso...